# What is the different between | and || in command line?

Tags: shell, unix

OS: Mac OS

`cat file.txt || ./a.out`, it works, but `cat file.txt | ./a.out` not work, why?

Where can I find the documents to learn it(I don't how to search it...)?

c code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  while (*++argv)
    printf("%s\n", *argv);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What does this have to do with the C language?

Comment: Both `cat file.txt || ./a.out` and `cat file.txt | ./a.out` work, but they do very different things.

Comment: @kaylum
I have added the c code, please look at it.

Comment: Please define "works" and "not work". Both commands do something and we can't say (but could guess) what "works" means unless you tell us what you are expecting that to do.

Comment: Since you are trying to understand shell syntax, it's reasonable to look through the documentation for your shell.   The bash man-page describes both operators fairly well.

Comment: In your example of a command that "works", it's `cat` writing to the screen, not `a.out` doing anything at all -- it isn't even run. `xargs ./a.out <file.txt` is perhaps what you're looking for?

Answer (score 1):

these are two different things

`cat file.txt | ./a.out` :

the output of `cat file.txt` will be given as input of `./a.out`

---

`cat file.txt || ./a.out` :

it's an "OR" operator, if `cat file.txt` fail, `./a.out` will be executed, but if  `cat file.txt` succeeds, `./a.out` will not be executed.

Comment: I see, thanks. a.out does not read the output of the 'cat'

Answer (score 1):

`||` and `|` as you show them are unix *shell* operators.  They may look similar, but `||` and `|` are totally different.

`|` is the *pipe* operator.  It connects the standard output of the left command to the standard input of the right command.

By default standard output of each command is the terminal screen.

```
% echo -e "a\nb\nc"                                                                                                                                                         
a
b
c
```

But the `|` operator lets us redirect that standard output to the standard input of the next command:

```
% echo -e "a\nb\nc" | grep a                                                                                                                                               
a
```

The shell handles [opening up a pipe](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html) and connecting its output and input  file descriptors to the left and right commands respectively.  The actual commands thus don't generally have to know or care whether their output is a terminal, a file, another program behind a pipe.

`||` is the logical *OR* operator.  It runs the second command if the first command does not return success exit code (ie `0`).

```
% test -f /usr/local/bin || echo "/usr/local/bin is not a file"                                                                                                            
/usr/local/bin is not a file
% test -f /bin/bash || echo "/bin/bash is not a file"
```

There is also a logical *and* operator that does the opposite:

```
% test -f /bin/bash && echo "/bin/bash is a file"                                                                                                                       
/bin/bash is a file
```

And that in turn should not be confused with the `&` operator, which puts the command in the background.

```
% sleep 3 &                                                                                                                                                                 
[1] 55981
% jobs                                                                                                                                                                      
[1]  + running    sleep 3
% fg                                                                                                                                                                        
[1]  + running    sleep 3
%
```

In general, shell syntax can be rather esoteric, and you should be aware that every shell is a little different (eg c/ bourne / korn shells vs bash vs zsh, the latter being now the standard on Mac Os)

This is all *completely* distinct from the command line arguments you access via `argv` and `argc`.  If you wanted the standard output of one command to be converted to *arguments* to the second command, `xargs` can do it.